# How do I change Stockfish's Engine Parameters?

Tags: engines, stockfish

I have no clue how to do this, I want to change its Contempt to -100.

Comment: You can do it by two ways. Command line or an user interface that supports it. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: @StudentT I prefer an user interface that supports it. If it helps, I use Scid vs. PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in the screenshot below. Goto Tools -> Analysis Engines -> Edit. You'll see a UCI configure dialog. In this example, I had another engine but the idea remains the same.

[image]