# Adjusting parameters in the engine stockfish 6

Tags: engines, stockfish

I downloaded Stockfish 6 (a binary file for Windows). It works, but I miss two things:

- The depth seems to be rather low. How can I increase the selectivity?
- How can I achieve that the engine uses the tablebases in advance? The program only seems to use them if 5 or less pieces are on the board.

I found the overview of the parameters, but I do not know the meaning of the topics.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What user interface are you using with Stockfish?

Comment: I just created and embedded the UCI-engine stockfish 6 into Shredder 9.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Shredder so I can't tell you how to use it to adjust parameters for Stockfish. However, it should be similar to ScidvsPC which I have posted [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/how-do-i-change-stockfishs-engine-parameters/8859#8859).

1. What do you mean by depth seems rather low? What depth would you consider be normal? We need a position to continue the discussion.
2. I don't think Shredder uses syzygy tablebase at all, that is you aren't using any tablebase. You'll need to set it up yourself.
3. Which parameters you're unsure? There're not many in SF6. The most important is **contempt factor**, which means how likely the engine takes a draw. By default, a draw is zero. If you give the contempt factor like a negative value, the engine will prefer another line that is closer to zero. Thus, the engine will take extra risks than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're using Stockfish directly and not through a GUI. In that case, you should use the command: go depth nnn
Where "nnn"  stands for your desired depth.

For example: go depth 20

I hope this helps